# Compute mean of control

Tags: spotfire

I'm migrating an analysis from R to Spotfire, and what's trivial in dplyr seems hard in Spotfire. I have a table with several experimental groups, each with treatments and controls. I want to compute the mean of controls for each experimental group.

Here's a sample:

```
+-------+------+-------+
| group | trmt | value |
+-------+------+-------+
|     a | cont |    32 |
|     a | cont |    28 |
|     a | t1   |    65 |
|     a | t1   |    57 |
|     a | t2   |    23 |
|     a | t2   |    19 |
|     b | cont |   132 |
|     b | cont |   128 |
|     b | t1   |   165 |
|     b | t1   |   157 |
|     b | t2   |   123 |
|     b | t2   |   119 |
+-------+------+-------+
```

and the desired output:

```
+-------+------+-------+-------------+
| group | trmt | value | meanControl |
+-------+------+-------+-------------+
| a     | cont |    32 |          30 |
| a     | cont |    28 |          30 |
| a     | t1   |    65 |          30 |
| a     | t1   |    57 |          30 |
| a     | t2   |    23 |          30 |
| a     | t2   |    19 |          30 |
| b     | cont |   132 |         130 |
| b     | cont |   128 |         130 |
| b     | t1   |   165 |         130 |
| b     | t1   |   157 |         130 |
| b     | t2   |   123 |         130 |
| b     | t2   |   119 |         130 |
+-------+------+-------+-------------+
```

In R, the logic is trivial:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.csv('xx.csv', as.is=T)

controls <- df           %>%
  filter(trmt == "cont") %>%
  group_by(group)        %>%
  summarize(meanControl=mean(value))

result <- df             %>%
  inner_join(controls, by="group")
```

What's a good approach to do this in Spotfire? Obviously I can do this with TERR but I want pure native Spotfire.

Comment: Did this work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a calculated column with this formula

```
Avg(if([trmt]="cont",[value])) over ([group])
```

Since you understand `R`, I assume you'll easily understand this formula or be able to understand it after reading about the `OVER` function but let me know if it needs explaining.